# Retrieving All Users in Parse C#

Tags: c#, parse-platform

I've managed to retrieve all objects in any class in my backend, apart from the users table. I'm guessing it's a little bit different as it doesn't want to work?

The following is my code working with an table in my database called Post

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseObject.GetQuery("Post");
            IEnumerable<ParseObject> posts = await query.FindAsync();
            foreach (ParseObject post in posts)
            {
                string content = post.Get<string>("content");
                txtNames2.Items.Add(content);
            }
```

Comment: What 'backend' are you referring to? What is the 'users' table? Context and alot more info is required.

Comment: The backend is Parse. If you knew anything about Parse, you'd know what I was talking about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally Worked it out!
Im guessing this is gonna help a lot of people, as there is no help on the Parse docs for how to retrieve users.

Heres how to do it!
I am retrieving all "objectId"s from all of my users and putting them into a combobox.

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.Query;
            IEnumerable<ParseUser> posts = await query.FindAsync();
            foreach (ParseUser post in posts)
            {
                string content = post.ObjectId;
                txtUsername.Items.Add(content);
            }
```

Hope that helps people!